# C++ Debugging no '=' operator found in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Visual Studio gives me this error when I try to compile my C++ project:

```
Severity: Error
Code: C2678
Description: binary '=': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
Project: jr
File: c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\utility
Line: 192
```

I suppose, somewhere in my project, I'm trying to change constant string. 
How do I locate this? How to go about debugging such errors?

The filename and line mentioned in the error are some read-only files by Microsoft. **I'd like to locate the error in my code.** Here's the excerpt of code around line 192:

```
_Myt& operator=(const _Myt& _Right)
        {   // assign from copied pair
        first = _Right.first;
        second = _Right.second;
        return (*this);
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you show us line 192 where the error is.

Comment: Is 'somewhere' a `Line: 192`?

Comment: If it is a compile error, Visual Studio will highlight that easily for you

Comment: Double clicking on an error message in the Error List or the Output window takes you to the line in question.

Comment: Look in the Output tab instead of the Error List. There will be a whole sequence of messages, starting with one about `operator=`. Scroll down until you find the problematic location in your own code. (The Error List is rubbish.)

Comment: @JasonHeine i've added the line to the question

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych Question clarified. Line 192 is in a read-only file by Microsoft.

Comment: @Draex_ in Visual Studio you should find the very first error line from output window, it should be from your own source code and not from the library.

Comment: @molbdnilo thanks! do you want to post your comment as an answer, so I could accept it?

Comment: @Draex_ It's not much of an answer really, and probably won't be generally useful. Glad I could be of help.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to write code like:

```
const std::string s;
s = "";
```

this is why error is saying about `const` type : 'const std::string'

Other possibility is that you want to assign a value to a string in a const method.